# Slipstream Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, slipstream

How do I slipstream Windows XP install an uptodate system on my computer when required?  I have a dell computer and the Windows XP cd is also from Dell.  When I manually install this CD, it does not ask me to enter in the license key, however, if I try to install this CD on any other computer, it asks me for a license key.

I have no intention of installing this anywhere, except on my own dell computer.  So with that in mind and the fact that my dell computer does not ask me for a license key when using the original dell windows xp cd, how do I slipstream this cd so it installs an uptodate version of windows xp, plus user accounts, plus drivers?

I have tried searching for guides on the internet, but they all keep talking about using program which ask me to enter in the license key, but I don't need to do that because somehow the cd is able to detect that the cd is for my computer only and probably automatically sets the license key?

Comment: Just as a note, it doesn't detect it's for your machine. It detects you are trying to install it on a Dell machine (dell hardware), and just does it. It's been my experience that you can take Dell windows disks and use it on any Dell machine to install key-less.

Comment: @Aeo - This is correct, I have a Selection of Dell OEM OS CD's / DVD's that I use on all Dell systems we purchase. Saves going through the box to grab the ones they provide with the system.

Comment: ...that's very weird. I'd think that Microsoft would not like dell doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried slipstreaming with the Dell CD before using Nlite - simple answer - it doesn't work.

The CD you have is an OEM manufacturers CD, the reason it doesn't ask for a key is because the CD detects that it is a Dell system in the BIOS and auto inputs the Dell OEM key.

Comment: So I'm out of luck? No other way for me to slipstream this

Comment: It will work.  I have slipstreamed many OEM discs (XP) with Nlite, including Dell.

Comment: @ typoknig, so I can slipstream my dell oem reinstallation cd with sp3, dell drivers, setup user accounts, and install ms essential security and create an unattended cd for my dell computer via nlite?

Comment: @ typoknig, did you have to type in the xp license key for the dell slipstreaming in nlite?

Comment: @oshirowanen I have never tried to automatically set up user accounts, so I cannot advise you there, but for drives and updates yes, if you know what you are doing.  It would be easiest to start with an OEM disc that has had all the crap (bloatware) removed (I am assuming you don't want that stuff), then the process would be relatively simple with Nlite.  Just download the disc where you get stuff.  You might get luck and find one with everything you need already done (except the user accounts of course).

Comment: @oshirowanen typically you do not have to type the key if you use a Dell OEM disc on a Dell, an HP OEM disc on an HP, ect. Sometimes you do though if the computer is significantly newer than the OEM disc you started with, but you can always enter the key (on sticker) manually and you will not have any issues. Worst case is you will have to phone and verify the key. You can install with the same key 3 times before you fail activation though, even then you will be ok when you call in.  Also, when you respond put the "@" right next to the user name like `@name` else that user will not be alerted.

Comment: @typoknig - How did you get it to work. I have slipstreamed XP many times using a VLK we own. Have tired the same with Dell OEM CD's and it always fails. The media is good so is there some kind of workaround you have to use?

Comment: @Joe Taylor, it has been a while since I have done it, (not having to mess configuring installs is after all the main reason for slipstreaming) but I do not recall having to do anything special, though I do remember I made a few coaster before I got it right. Now I have a slipstreamed XP disc for HP, Dell, Gateway, and Toshiba, all with SP3 and the common drivers. For whatever reason my Dell disc is very liberal, it never asks for a key at install, but it fails registration unless it is actually installed on the correct Dell PC. I'm sure there are other similar quirks you will /have run into.

Comment: I just tried nlite, when I tried finishing, it gave an error which I ignored, when when buring the iso to disk, the burn process failed...